# Foreach inside foreach delete element issue

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I have two arrays.
I am looping first array and checking if value exist in second array and deleting that element from second array.

Here is my code.

$options = array();

```
  "OptionValues": [ 
         { 
            "OptionId": "22",  
            "OptionName": "Gener" 
         },
         { 
            "OptionId": "21",
            "OptionName" : "Gener"
         } 

  foreach($OptionValues as $optValue){
                    $optionIdVal = $optValue['OptionId'];
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        if($option['value'] == $optionIdVal){
                            unset($option['value']);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

$options is an associative array with key value pairs. which i am fetching dynamically. so not specified above.

This is working only for first time and skipping next element check. Please anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: @Andreas, using php i am doing this

Comment: This code you posted seems incomplete, or at least, it's hard to understand. Is the "OptionValues" variable supposed to be inside an array, or? It's not valid php right now so it's hard to debut that.

Comment: @Ryan, Optionvalues is an array, I am reading from json, just I have posted as it is

Comment: Please post `$options` array. From your description, it is unclear as you are using `value` as key.

Comment: @pupil, yes it has name n value, I think its not required, because I am checking with Optionvalues array, for reference I posted as empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove from `$options` array not `$option` sub array.

Also, please get the key while looping over `$options` array and remove by key.

Working example:

```
<?php
$OptionValues = [
 ["OptionId" => "22", "OptionName" => "Gener"],
 ["OptionId" => "21", "OptionName" => "Gener"]
];
$options = [];
$options[] = ['value' => 17];
$options[] = ['value' => 18];
$options[] = ['value' => 19];
$options[] = ['value' => 20];
$options[] = ['value' => 21];
$options[] = ['value' => 22];
echo '<br/>$options array before: ';
echo '<pre>';print_r($options);echo '</pre>';
foreach($OptionValues as $optValue){
 $optionIdVal = $optValue['OptionId'];
 foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
  if($option['value'] == $optionIdVal){
   unset($options[$key]);
  }
 }
}
echo '<br/>$options array After: ';
echo '<pre>';print_r($options);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output**

$options array before:

```
Array(
 [0] => Array([value] => 17)
 [1] => Array([value] => 18)
 [2] => Array([value] => 19)
 [3] => Array([value] => 20)
 [4] => Array([value] => 21)
 [5] => Array([value] => 22)
)
```

$options array After:

```
Array(
 [0] => Array([value] => 17)
 [1] => Array([value] => 18)
 [2] => Array([value] => 19)
 [3] => Array([value] => 20)
)
```